# Monogame collision bug

Tags: c#, xna, game-physics, monogame

I began to create a platformer with Monogame and C# recently and got a strange bug with ground collision. I made block and player, both use bounding collisions like this:

```
public Rectangle Collision
{
    get => new Rectangle((int)_pos.X, (int)_pos.Y, _w, _h);
}
//Only for player entity
public Rectangle GroundCollision
{
    get => new Rectangle((int)_pos.X, (int)_pos.Y+_w, _w, 1);
}
```

It works good, though sometimes space appears space ply and ground like so:

[image: this].

Both block and player textures are white, but distance in 1 pix is visible. After some jumps (sometimes with movement) may fix it, though after it began to hover again. Here is player update code:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (_movable)
    {
        Vector2 oldPos = _pos;
        _pos += new Vector2(_vel, -_acc);
        if(_pos.Y >= 96)
        {
            bool c = Collides;
        }
        if (Grounded)
        {
            _pos += new Vector2(0, _acc);
            _acc = 0;
        }
        /*if (Collides)
        {
            _pos = oldPos;
        }*/
    }
}

//Entity Methods
protected void _Move(float dir, float delta)
{
    _vel = (float) _speed * dir * delta;
}

protected void _Gravity(float delta)
{
    float fallspeed = (float) Math.Round(Phys.gravity * delta * -5f);
    if (_acc - fallspeed >= 0)
        _acc = fallspeed;
    else if (_acc >= 0)
        _acc = 0;
}

protected void _Jump(float delta)
{
    _acc += _jumpForce * delta * 10f;
}
```

So, is there any ways to fix this?

Comment: I assume because your final position is not full number, but contain some decimals... and because of those decimals, gaps appear.

Comment: Try rounding it to the nearest number with with Math.round, maybe that'll help.